# Validate CPU virtualization support on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu, virtualization

On Windows 7 hosts, how do I validate that CPU virtualization support such as AMD-V or VT-x is enabled without rebooting the machine and installing additional or third-party software. In that case, these drop out:

- BIOS settings
- VirtualBox, VMware ...
- *Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool* by Microsoft

Comment: Look up the CPU on the AMD or Intel website.

Comment: I do not talk about a product features. I am looking for a solution while using a machine which does have a supportive CPU. Is it possible to _validate that CPU virtualization support ... is enabled_?

Comment: Apart from checking with the BIOS or using the tools you mention I don't think you can. Windows, from what is logical, doesn't need to check if it is enabled as it doesn't use it, it's only when you come to using such tools as XP Mode, VirtualBox etc. and then why would these need to check with Windows to see if virtualization is enabled? A waste of a process IMO. Go direct to the processor for best performance... I might be wrong...

Comment: @BigChris You might be right. `WMIC` doesn't return any info from `wmic:root\cli>cpu get /format:list` about Virtualization and that's pretty much the best list you can get from Windows natively.

Comment: I just think logically... If Windows did support checking if it's enabled why do they get you to download an app to check before XP Mode can be used? If it isn't enabled or available you have to download a fix... kind of answers the question...

Comment: The Microsoft tool you listed is a standalone program which doesn't get installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *no native* way to get the information about CPU support for vitualization in Windows 7 including WMIC.

You ask for a non third party software and no installation (and no rebooting). 
Does [MS Technet Sysinternals Coreinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) is acceptable for you?

Comment: Since I dump the SysInternals suite on every host it's like out-of-the-box. Extra points for CLI only.

Answer (score 2):

[SecurAble](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm) does not require installation.

[image]